# PHP Include() whole subdirectory with jQuery navigation bar

Tags: php, jquery, include, directory, subdirectory

I have a subdirectory folder called /lefnav

It contains this files:

```
background.jpg
demo.html
heading_bg.jpg
jquery.js
navigation.jpg
sliding_effect.js
styles.css
tab_bg.jpg
Thumbs.db
Thumbs.db/encryptable
```

It actually contains al the elements of this tutorial:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-a-mootools-homepage-inspired-navigation-effect-using-jquery/

I want to include with php the whole folder so that the final result is (like this demo):

http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/004_Moo/tutorial/demo/demo.html

The best I´ve go so far is, but it is not working at all even if I add .css and .js:

```
<?php
foreach (glob("leftnav/*html") as $filename) {
    include($filename);
}
?>
```

I would have thought:

```
include("leftnav/demo.html");
```

Alone should work because it seams logical that when I include the and .html file it should call fot the .css etc but this is not the case for what I see.

EDIT:

I think I´ve sorted where the problem is:

When I include the .html it does call for the css but it calls for it in the wrong folder, it does not add "/leftnav/" how could I solve this?

Comment: what do you expect from including into PHP code a picture?

Comment: No idea, sorry! now that you say so, not really smart!

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel already deleted it to prevent confusion. Sorry about that!

Comment: always use absolute path, starting from the `/`. `<img src="/leftnav/navigation.jpg">` etc.

Answer (score 2):

WOW.

You must include your .js files like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/your/file"></script>
```

Css files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/your/css/file" />
```

All of this in a .php file.

Comment: I do understand that but I´m looking for a way to include my whole folder not the files one by one.

Comment: I just don't get why are you trying to do so... The image files will, most likely, be "linked" by the css or the js files....

Comment: I want to include the contents demo.html in another file which is higher folder. Better?

Comment: @Trufa : are you want call whole folder? but in html you must call one by one file. that make a particular function works.one file for all same function.

Comment: @klox Could you please expand a little bit? Some example code or seudo-code?? Thank you very much!